# Unable to get notification at client side when MonitoringItem has been deleted from OPC UA Source Server

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, opc-ua

We are developing one OPC UA Client application using C#, .NET Core and OPC.UA.Client library. But currently facing one problem. Following section contains sample of our code,

```
MonitoredItem monItem = new MonitoredItem((uint)sampleID) { };
monItem.StartNodeId = NodeId.Parse(item.NodeId);
monItem.AttributeId = Attributes.Value;
monItem.SamplingInterval = 0;
monItem.DisplayName = item.DisplayName.ToString();
monItem.DiscardOldest = true;
monItem.QueueSize = 1;
monItem.Notification += MonItem_Notification;
```

As you can see from the above code sample, we have notification event for MonitoringItem object, which is providing us with all the value updates for the monitoring item. But this notification event is not getting triggered when monitoring item has been deleted from the server side. Hence we are not getting any notification at the client side.

Need some code, where we receive notification at client side about monitoring item deletion at server side.

Note: We cannot change OPC UA Server code. Hence need modification at client side only.

Comment: have you thought about a timeout? what is the problem when the notification is not triggered?

Comment: Why is the server deleting some Monitored Item ? OPC UA Server should only do that when they think the associated Subscription is garbage... This can be the case if your OPC UA Client is not sending enough Publish Requests to the Server...

Comment: @DonMiguelSanchez Timeout happens for entire session, right? We are considering some situation where server is sending data for multiple monitoring items. And after some time, one/multiple monitoring nodes are getting deleted from client side. In that case, we need to continue subscription for all other monitoring nodes and for those few neither any data is coming nor any notification. This is creating inconvenience .

Comment: @CamilleG.We are considering a scenario, where subscription is fine. But in between that subscription user makes some modifications for some monitoirng nodes in the server. As a result, some monitoring nodes are being deleted, which had already been subscribed by the client application. We need to pass some notification to client users that those monitoring nodes have been deleted.

Comment: @TheKingmaker if the action that leads to deletion of the monitored items is triggered by an OPC UA client, you might have a change while listening to AuditEvents of the OPC UA Server